# For an Op-amp with a single power supply, how do you get negative voltage

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier

In my design, I am connecting an LM324 op-amp in the inverting mode and thus the output voltage would be negative of the input multiplied by th gain. But I am using a 5v and 0V power supply. So how is it possible to get a negative output when my power supply cannot have negative value. Do I need a dual power supply to achieve this?[image: my circuit schematic]

The frequency range of both bandpass filters is from 0.7 hertz to 2.5 hertz.  Both op amps should provide enough gain to raise my weak signal (+-0.3v) up to the TTL logic level of my microcontroller I.e around 4.7 v , if not I would add a comparator to do that.

Comment: You can't, and yes you do.

Comment: Is your input signal AC or DC?

Comment: My input is a constant 2v with a regular +-0.3v fluctuation on top.

Comment: You could reference the output to the mid-rails (2.5V), but whether this makes sense depends on your whole circuit.

Comment: Do you _need_ the output to go negative (below 0V) or can it be between 0V and +5V?

Comment: It's conceivable that you could use capacitive coupling on the input and/or output, but unless you post a schematic (good) or a detailed verbal description of what you're trying to do,  (not so good) it's all just guesswork.

Comment: @BruceAbbott I do not need my  output to be negative but whenever you connect  an op amp in the inverting mode is it not always inverted? My fear is that when my output is inverted,  it would go to zero because of my 5v and 0v supply.

Comment: @ozioma. Are you confusing an inverted output with a negative (below ground) voltage? With a single-ended power supply the op-amp output will NOT go below ground voltage unless the signal swing is great enough.

Comment: If your signal only has a range of ±0.3V then there would appear to be no danger of hitting the rail if you design your circuit properly. (i.e. with an offset of 2~3 volts.  Since we don't know where the signal is going, we are limited in what we can suggest of a practical nature.

Comment: @RichardCrowley. Granted that much depends on the OP making specific statements about values or provides a schematic. It is possible that neither answer is correct, and cannot be determined without input from the OP.

Comment: I think there is a confusion here between 'negative' and phase inversion. " in the **inverting mode** and thus the **output voltage would be negative** of the input multiplied by the gain. But I am using a 5v and 0V power supply. So how is it possible **to get a negative output**

Comment: I have added  a schematic above.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a voltage inverter like [the LMC7660](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmc7660.pdf) to generate a negative rail for your op amp.  It converts any voltage between 1.5V and 10V into its negative counterpart -- e.g. +5V in, -5V out.  Only good for a few mA though.

Comment: Why the down-vote?  Perfectly acceptable answer!

Comment: @Sparky256 The OP specifically asked how to get a negative output -- that was the part of the question I was trying to answer (and that's also the way the title is phrased).

Comment: You could always use a part with the charge pump already on board: https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/analog/amplifiers/MAX44267.html

Comment: @tcrosley. I missed that one, but the OP had not submitted a diagram yet. But I did miss-interpret the context of the question-and got it backwards. sigh...

Answer (score 3):

The inverting input of an op amp produces a negative output *relative to the non inverting input*. So if your signal is 2V +-0.3V then you can set the non inverting input's 'ground' reference to 2V and the output will also be relative to 2V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fePYbW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: The LM324 struggles to pull down below 0.6V, but without knowing the application we can't say that this will be a problem. The OP didn't specify gain or output voltage limits either, so I just went for the simplest answer.

Comment: I have added a schematic above

Comment: Signal is AC coupled so no 2VDC to worry about. Just bias each non-inverting input to 2.5V with a resistor divider (like in my circuit) and you are good to go.